# Get data from calendar in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, calendar

I am making a php calendar that my client can use to schedule his employees. It is a weekly calendar, and under the calendar all the employees are listed:

[image]

Under each day I want there to be a button of some sort to be able to schedule that employee for that certain day, however I am unsure how to process this. The PHP will be on a different page that the calendar, and I need to be able to submit the data to a database. Any suggestions?

Calendar-

```
<?php
 $dt = new DateTime;
 if (isset($_GET['year']) && isset($_GET['week'])) {
     $dt->setISODate($_GET['year'], $_GET['week']);
} else {
     $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
}
 $year = $dt->format('o');
 $week = $dt->format('W');
?>

 <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week-1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Pre Week</a> <!--Previous week-->
 <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?week='.($week+1).'&year='.$year; ?>">Next Week</a> <!--Next week-->

 <table border="1px" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td align="center">Employee</td>
 <?php
 do {
echo "<td align='center'>" . $dt->format('l') . "<br>" . $dt->format('d M Y') . "</td>\n";
$dt->modify('+1 day');
} while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
 echo $LS->add_shifts_to_employees();
?>
```

Function-

```
function add_shifts_to_employees($a = null){ 
    $user_biz_id = self::getUser('db_biz_id');
    $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM ". $this->config['db']['table'] ." WHERE ". $this->config["db"]["columns"]["db_biz_id"] ." = '$user_biz_id'");
    $sql->execute();
    $data = null;

    foreach($sql as $line){
    $name = $line['f_name'];

    $data .= "<tr align='center'><td>". $name ."</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
    }

    return $data;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [PHP Event Calendar](http://supercali.inforest.com/).
Not the solution probably but if you want to try by your self:

1. Put a select on each slot.
2. Put a send button for the superuser to send the data. You can use JS libraries for retrieving data in `<table>`.

2'. You must design a table for user and date, so that this it's read when completing the calendar.

3. Once the data is send the site reloads and the clicked slots should appear clicked.

Hope it helps.